# is there a way to choose which object to return based on it's attribute in vuex?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex, store

I have an array of objects named Employees and am trying to get the ones who are department_id=3 and I don't want to go back to laravel and make another request so is there a way to do so with vuex?

```
     "id": 25,
    "name": "name",
    "email": "name@gmail.com",
    "last_name": "lastname",
    "phone": "98745632",
    "gender": "Male",
    "nationality": "Tunisian",
    "school": "ISIMM",
    "experience_level": "2",
    "source": "Linkedin",
    "hiring_date": "2020-04-17",
    "end_contract": "2020-04-18",
    "position": "web developer",
    "grade": "Junior",
    "contract": "Cdi",
    "department_id": 1,
    "company_id": 1,
    "archived": "0",
    "img": null,
    "supervisor_id": 1,
    "ipAdress": null,
    "last_login_at": null,
    "department": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "mobile"
    },
```

here's 
**state :**

```
const employee = {
  state: {
    Employees: [],
    sysAdmins: [],
  },
```

here's 
**getters :**

```
  sysAdmins: (state) =>
state.Employees.map((element) => (element.department_id = "3")),


 Employees: (state) => state.Employees,
```

here's 
**mutations :**

```
  getsysAdmins(state, employees) {
state.sysAdmins = employees;
```

},

```
  getEmployees(state, employees) {
state.Employees = employees;
```

},

here's
**actions :**

```
  getEmployees(context) {
const config = {
  headers: {
    "x-api-key": process.env.VUE_APP_SIRH_X_API_KEY,
    Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
  },
};
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios
    .get("/employees/all_employees", config)
    .then((response) => {
      context.commit("getEmployees", response.data.data.users);
      context.commit("getsysAdmins", response.data.data.users);

      resolve(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
});
```

},

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it right, you want to return the while Employee Object for those employees that work in a certain department.
You can do this by filtering your Employees array. I would write that as following:

```
getters: {
  employees: (state) => state.Employees,
  sysAdmins: (state) => state.Employees.filter((employee) => employee.department_id === 3),
  // If your DB returns a string as the department_id, you'll have to check against "3"
}
```

If sysAdmins is always a subset of the employees, it makes more sense to always use a getter instead of placing these in a separate array in the state.

Some other notes:
- You mutations are called `get...` while these are setters, it might be best to rename these.
- In your action, you currently set the same result as employees and sysAdmins. Again, I would just set employees and always filter the sysAdmins from that array.

Comment: it worked, thank you 
can you explain to me more what did you mean about mutations? (your notes)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

check the result using `console.log` to make it sure.

```
const newValue = {
   ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employees")),
   department.id: 3
}

localStorage.setItem("Employees", JSON.stringify(newValue))
```

or

```
// Get the user from localStorage and parse into object
let department = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Employees"));
// Update an attribute on the user object
Employees.department.id = 2;
// Update the user in localStorage and stringify to string
localStorage.setItem("Employees", JSON.stringify(Employees));
```